# Merge Wordpress .htaccess with another script

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress website and I want to place an application to a third level domain, but I stuck on nonfunctional .htaccess script.

First part of code is basic .htaccess configuration for WordPress like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Second part of script is this. Everything what is in folder ***subdom*** will be third level domain.

```
RewriteEngine On

# cele domeny (aliasy)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI]

# subdomeny (s nebo bez www na zacatku)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI]

# aliasy - spravne presmerovani pri chybejicim /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]

# subdomeny - spravne presmerovani pri chybejicim /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^subdom/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]
```

If both parts are alone they work perfectly, but if I merge it togeather the problem comes!

I have tried exclude folder with my application from the first part of script with this code, but it is not good. The application folder located in subdom folder is called ***masaze***

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(masaze) [NC]
RewriteRule ^masaze/.$ - [PT]
```

Can you please help me resolve this riddle?

Comment: Did you added the Wordpress part after your rules? Or before?

Comment: The Wordpress part has to be after my rules otherwise wordpres site do not work at all

Answer (score 0):

> but if I merge it togeather the problem comes!

Don't merge the two scripts into the same .htaccess file. Create a second .htaccess in the `/subdom` folder for the "second part of the script". (This is preferable since it keeps the separate application *separate*.)

Providing you are only using mod_rewrite, which you appear to be, then the code in `/subdom/.htaccess` will completely override `/.htaccess` when accessed via your subdomain.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but it didnt resolve it. I put like you said the second part of the script to folder /subdom and it is completely the same like it was. :-(